# Not able to make my class managed bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, liferay, managed-bean

I have a userManagement.xhtml file name as UserManagement in my portlet and I have included 3 more xhtml files in different panels

my userManagement.xhtmlpage is basically like this

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel rendered="#{userManagement.condition}">
         <ui:include src="userTable.xhtml"/>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel rendered="#{userManagement.condition}"/>
         <ui:include src="userDetails.xhtml"/>
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel rendered="#{userManagement.condition}"/>
         <ui:include src="userActivity.xhtml"/>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Based on rendering condition I use to show one of the 3 xhtml file(panel) to user.

For managing these I have 1 managed bean name as UserManagement.java. There are 3 more files for other 3 xhtml file.

I tried to make UserTable.java, UserDetails.java and userActivity.java but I am getting

```
com.example.useroperations.UserTable cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.UIComponent
```

Right now I am using this as a normal java class by creating object and using it in UserManagement.java. But I would like to make it managed bean.

My Java code is like this
UserManagement.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
class UsermanageMent{
private UserTable userTable;

public void showUserTable(){
     this.userTable = new UserTable("some param");
     ...
     ...
}

public void setUserTable(UserTable userTable){
   this.userTable = userTable
}

public getUserTable(){
   return this.userTable();
}

}
```

UserTable.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public UserTable{
   ......
   ......

   public UserTable(String param){
        ......
        this.retrieveListOfUser(param);

   }
   public void retrieveListOfUser(String param){
       ......
       ......
       SomeOtherClass obj = new SomeOtherClass();
       obj.retrieve();    // This is for DB call
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your java code?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I have posted my java code

Comment: `UserTable` is not intended to be a managed bean. This class will be a wrapper for a `List` of users. Managed beans are supposed to just contain it. So avoid `UserTable` being a managed bean. Apart from that, where are you referencing the table from? Remember that everything that is included by an `ui:include` will be evaluated before `rendered` attributes. This happens because `ui:include` works at view build time while `rendered` works at view render time. So the correct way to do what you want would be `c:choose` as long as you keep using `ui:include`.

Comment: @XtremeBiker In userTable.xhtml I have some components to filter dataTable(primefaces). And their corresponding java methods in UserTable.java. So is this not the condition to have managed bean?

Comment: It isn't as long as it is included into a managed bean. You can reference it as `viewBean.userTable`. You need of course a getter method for Jsf to be able to reach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of this problem is my datatable binding #{userTable} and my managed bean UserTable which will be same #{userTable}.

Due to this I was getting

com.example.useroperations.UserTable cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.UIComponent

I just changed my dataTable binding as #{userDataTable}. And after that it worked. :)